# How to find remainder of $31^{41^{101}}$ from division by 53?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

When we see such a big and difficult to calculate number, we want to use Fermat's little theorem (especially when we see prime number as divider)

But how do we approach situation when we have number in power of number in power? And what if we had something like "find remainder of $13^{5^{53}}$ from division by 48". It is already not a prime number, what would we have to change in our solution?

Comment: We use [Euler's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem). In fact we may need this for your original question.

Comment: The answer is $20$.

Comment: I got $45$ and $13$

Comment: note that $5^4\equiv1\bmod \phi(48)$